# Mapping Through 3 MongoD collections

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, playframework, map-function

I am trying to map through monogdb collections(I implement DAOs for all my database activities. I am using play framework) but i am having trouble achieving this. I have 3 collections that i am trying to compare and return their JSON objects.

```
 def make=Action.async{

  val person= PersonDAO.correlationData
  val vehicle= VehicleDAO.correlationData
  val incident= IncidentDAO.correlationData

  person.map{x =>
      vehicle.map{ y =>
        incident.map{z =>
          if(x == y == z){
            println("related")
          }
          else
            println("not related")
        }
      }
  }
    println("here")
}
```

This does not print anything because i have a type mismatch return type.
If this information helps, i am trying to achieve a 1:3, 3:1, 1:2,2:1,1:3 and 3:1 correlation, meaning, compare all three collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may stumble opon this issue. I found a way to resolve this actually...Turned out to be easier than i expected. I used a for-yield statement to send all of my response to my Angular controller and then ended up with something like this

```
def make=Action.async{

  val person= PersonDAO.correlationData
  val vehicle= VehicleDAO.correlationData
  val incident= IncidentDAO.correlationData


    for {
      person <- person
      vehicle <- vehicle
      incident <- incident
    } yield Ok(Json.obj("person" -> Json.toJson(person) , "vehicle" -> Json.toJson(vehicle), "incident" -> Json.toJson(incident)))

}

}
```

Maybe there is a more efficient way to do this..but for now, this works for me and i can easily manipulate my data with angularjs.In my angular controller, i can map through my data and do what i need to do.